# Does a twinned spell with an XP component cost twice as much XP as the normal spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, experience-points, metamagic, spell-components

If I cast a spell with an XP component using the metamagic feat Twin Spell (CAr pg. 84), will I have to pay the XP component twice as if I had cast the spell twice? Or is the XP cost unchanged?

Comment: What spell is being twinned? (Carcer's answer, for example, subtly points to the restrictions on the Twin Spell feat—the original spell is either a targeted spell or an area spell. A twinned *simulacrum*, for example, is invalid as *simulacrum* has neither an area entry nor a target entry.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Limited Wish, by an Incantatrix as a 9th level spell after two level reductions on Twin Spell. He wanted to use with Gate or Wish, but he can't cast a 11th level spell.

Comment: Huh. In that case, *limited wish* to do what? O, or is he picking to twin the *limited wish* so as to do two different things? Because *that* is pretty clever… so much so that it may warrant another question!

Comment: @HeyICanChan To do two different things. He doesn't haven any specific ideas yet, he just wants to know if he can as a trump card without paying the XP twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The components of a twinned spell don't change

The metamagic is thematically described as casting a single spell twice, which might make you conclude you need to pay any component costs twice. However, the mechanical effect is that:

> Casting a twinned spell **causes the spell to take effect twice** in the same area or on the same target simultaneously.

You are still only casting a single spell - it is the spell's *effect*, not the entire spell, that is duplicated. You're not actually casting it twice, and the feat doesn't say anywhere that you have to provide extra components when you modify the spell this way, so in terms of material or XP costs nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Probably yes**

The key sentence is the first one in the Twinned Spell feat description:

> You can simultaneously cast a single spell twice.

Note that you are not casting a spell that *takes effect* twice, the spell is being *cast* twice.  Therefore, the XP cost should be paid twice.

There appear to be a limited number of spells with an XP component that this metamagic feat could benefit, given the requirement to use a spell slot four levels higher than the spell's actual level and that both spells are cast on the same target.  Atonement and Permanency have no benefit if repeated on the same target, especially as neither spell requires a saving throw.  Planar Ally, Lesser is one of the few spells that might benefit from this, but it would rely on one of the called creatures being willing to wait until bargaining had been concluded with the other.  (This GM would not allow for collective bargaining with multiple called creatures, but others might.)

Comment: Could you please source your quote? I cannot find any such wording in the description of the feat in either *Tome of Blood*, *Complete Arcane* or *Forgotten Realm Campaign Setting*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it's the short first line of the feat's description in *Complete Arcane*, pg 84 (before the prereq/benefit sections).

Comment: @Carcer: Thanks; I had only looked at the normative descriptions, not the non-normative fluff! Interestingly, they changed this part from the Tome of Blood short-hand: *You can cast a spell simultaneously with another spell similar to it*.